# How to use console.log for a custom function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi following is my code:

```
const tst = require("trucksim-telemetry")

const telemetry = tst()

function update(data) {
  console.log('Speed Limit:',data.navigation.speedLimit)
  console.log('Speed:',data.truck.speed)
  console.log('Controls:',data.controls.input)
  console.log('ADAS:',data.truck.cruiseControl.enabled)
}

telemetry.watch({interval: 12}, update)
```

I can log everything from the `function update(data)` successfully into a `txt` file but I want to also log

```
telemetry.watch({interval: 12}, update)
```

such as it shows me time (ms): 0 12 24 and so on till I close the script. I tried using `setinterval` function but it sometimes logs an interval multiple times. I'm sorry if my question is vague I'm new to javascript*.

Comment: telemetry takes the interval as seconds and setTimeOut takes the time as milisecond, but both will continue invoking the function forever. But is this what you wanted? Your question is kind of unclear.

Comment: @SifatAmin I'm using a plugin for telemetry which initially logs all data every microsecond. But I want data every 12 ms (80hz) for my project. And yes, I want it to run until I make it stop bymyself.

Comment: @trincot haha helps my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try capturing the time from when you start running the script, and have the `update()` subtract from that value every time it is invoked:

```js
const now = new Date() // capture start time
const telemetry = tst()

function update(data) {
  console.log('Time (ms):', new Date() - now) // time elapsed in ms
  console.log('Speed Limit:',data.navigation.speedLimit)
  console.log('Speed:',data.truck.speed)
  console.log('Controls:',data.controls.input)
  console.log('ADAS:',data.truck.cruiseControl.enabled)
}

telemetry.watch({interval: 12}, update)
```

Alternatively, if you are trying to plot with multiples of 12, you can add a counter and multiply that by 12ms

```js
let counter = 0
const telemetry = tst()

function update(data) {
  counter++
  console.log('Time (ms):', counter*12) // difference is in ms
  console.log('Speed Limit:',data.navigation.speedLimit)
  console.log('Speed:',data.truck.speed)
  console.log('Controls:',data.controls.input)
  console.log('ADAS:',data.truck.cruiseControl.enabled)
}

telemetry.watch({interval: 12}, update)
```

Comment: How to do it? Im really sorry but I started working on javascript 1 week ago

Comment: I've added two lines onto what you wrote in your question. You can see the lines I added have comments behind them

Comment: Have you tried to add the new lines number 1 and number 5 of the answer? @samir93

Comment: Thankyou for responding so quick. It logs time with different intervals, cant the time be logged at the same rate as my interval of 12ms? Like if it starts from 0 12 24 36 48 and so on? Your edit in the code works atleast I have some kind of time now before I didnt have anything.

Comment: The polling rate and the time for which the function may not be exactly 12ms, and there will always be discrepancies. 

What you can do is instead of using time, you can add a counter instead and multiply that by 12 for each consequent function call, and log it out to the console, but that's not what your question is.

Comment: Like I said I'm sorry if my question was vaguely presented; But yes I want to log intervals after every 12 ms because that's the time it takes my pc to run the function "telemetry.watch({interval: 12}, update)". So when Im to log all data it should be with increment of 12 so that I can trace back fluctuations in results

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your comments

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `Date` class keeps time by milliseconds. So you can handle this by putting this line just before the `.watch` call.

```
const start = new Date();
```

then in the `update` function add

```
console.log ('Time:'.(Date.now - start));
```